# Binary diff of two folders

Tags: diff, binary

Let's say I have two folders: `before` and `after`.

```
./before:
bash

./after:
bash
```

The `bash` in the `before` folder differs from the `bash` in `after`.

Using `bsdiff` or a similar program, is there a way to create a binary patch between the two folders? The program does not have to support Windows. New files in the `after` directory need to be included with the patch file as well.

The reason I don't want to package `after` as a whole is to minimize the size of the patch.

Comment: What is your goal in making a patch rather than simply taring up `after`? Just minimizing the size, or do you also expect something sensible to happen if the patch is applied to a directory tree that is slightly different from `before`? Apart from file names and contents, do you need to preserve metadata (timestamps, ownership, etc.)?

Comment: I want to minimize the size of my patch for convenience. And no, I don't need to preserve timestamps and ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xdelta` program does exactly what you are looking for:

> Name        : xdelta
>
> Description : Xdelta (X for XCF: the eXperimental Computing Facility
>   at Berkeley) is a binary delta generator (like a diff program for
>   binaries) and an RCS version control replacement library. Xdelta uses
>   a binary file delta algorithm to replace the standard diff program
>   used by RCS

Comment: It appears this doesn't support folders, though there seems to be some type of [perl script](https://github.com/jmacd/xdelta/issues/21#issuecomment-85331737) that accomplishes this task.

Comment: That program worked exactly as I wanted it to, and it helped me even further with the [xdelta3-dir-patcher](https://github.com/endlessm/xdelta3-dir-patcher) wrapper program.